# flask background task using `threading.Thread` is blocking main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, flask, eventlet

I have a long-running background task that spins the flask app again and to do some auditing in the background. The front end is a web application and uses socketio to communicate with the backend main flask app to handle multiple async behaviors.

I make sure to only fire the background task when the main thread is created and I do `eventlet.monkey_patch()` only at the very beginning of the script.

if the background thread has a lot of stuff to audit, it blocks the main thread, the more stuff in memory, the longer it blocks the main thread. The audit is not CPU intensive at all, it's just some db inserts and logging.

- The items that need to be audited are added to an object in memory from the main thread and are passed by reference to the child thread. (Like a in memory queue)
- If I don't monkey patch eventlet, then everything works fine but then flask's auto reload won't work, and I need it for development.
- I run the app like socketio.run(app) in dev
- Behavior persists when using gunicorn/eventlet
- When the background task is sleeping `sleep(2)`, there's no block happening.

```py
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

# ... rest of code is a basic flask app create_app factory that at some # point starts the new thread if it's the main thread

# the async code that runs is the following

class AsyncAuditor(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, tasks: list, stop: threading.Event):
        super().__init__()
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.stop_event = stop

    def run(self):
        from app import init_app
        from dal import db

        app = init_app(mode='sys')
        app.logger.info('starting async audit thread')

        with app.app_context():
            try:
                while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                    if len(self.tasks) > 0:
                        task: dict
                        for task in self.tasks:
                            app.logger.debug(threading.current_thread().name + ' new audit record')
                            task.payload = encryptor.encrypt(task.payload)
                            task.ip = struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(task.ip))[0]
                            db.session.add(task)
                        self.tasks.clear()
                        db.session.commit()
                    sleep(2)
                app.logger.info('exiting async audit thread')
            except BaseException as e:
                app.logger.exception('Exception')

# there's some code that tries to gracefully exit if app needs to exit

stop_event = threading.Event()
async_task = AsyncAuditor(API.audit_tasks, stop_event)
async_task.start()

def exit_async_thread():
    stop_event.set()
    async_task.join()


atexit.register(exit_async_thread)
```

I expect that while the child thread is working, the main thread would not be blocked by any db operations, in fact, like I mentioned before, if I don't monkey patch eventlet, then everything works fine in the main thread and the child one as well. Instead, I'm getting 9 and even 30 seconds delays when hitting an endpoint in the flask application while the background task is working.

Comment: What database are you using, and what type of encryption are you doing, and on what size of payloads?

Comment: db: PostgreSQL, Encryption: AES symmetric cipher via simple-crypt, payloads: `"query": {{"page":"1","orderBy":"updated_on","orderDir":"desc"}}` one example that blocks, there're other larger payloads but not significantly. Payloads are converted to json in the main process regardless of whether it is query string, form, or json payload.

Comment: Turns out that the encryption it's actually clogging the cpu. I benchmarked its performance and it's extremely slow. Thanks for pointing that out @Miguel.

Comment: The same reason why I moved this to a thread it's the reason why I can't have it in a thread. I wonder if there's a better pattern for doing something like this in the background. Because of the nature of it, I don't really need to monkey patch, but wonder if there's a way I can still have the autoreload work.

Comment: I think the thread would be a bit nicer to the rest of the system if you add a `sleep(0)` inside the task loop, but I'm not sure if that will be enough. If that doesn't work, then you can move this work to a separate process and use a proper queue to pass the data into it. There are unfortunately no magical solutions, async and CPU usage are mortal enemies.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel. I ended up creating two different runtime behaviors where the app is monkey patched in dev and encryption is skipped, and in prod monkey patching is skipped and encryption is enabled. I had tried sleeping inside the task loop but that only made it slightly more tolerable. I actually learned a lot about greenlet threads in this journey so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.